# RedShift - Identity seed value not respected in some circumstances when inserting initial single value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, identity-column

I have an identity field in one of my tables, specified as

```
User_Key BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(-1,1) NOT NULL
```

The seed is set to -1 to account for an unknown value (universal across all my tables) and the table in question is appended to rather than being dropped and recreated each time, but the process is set up to recreate the table if it is accidentally dropped.

Since RedShift doesn't support if statements (ideally, I'd only insert the unknown value if the table didn't already exist), my workaround (using EXCEPT) is shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBL
        (User_Key BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(-1,1) NOT NULL
        ,Col1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        ,Col2 INT
        ,COL3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

INSERT INTO TBL
        (Col1
        ,Col2
        ,Col3)
SELECT
        'Unknown'
        NULL
        'Etc'
EXCEPT
SELECT
        Col1
        ,Col2
        ,Col3
FROM TBL
```

With the EXCEPT clause, the value in the User_Key field varies (but never is -1 as expected). Without the EXCEPT clause, the User_Key field works exactly as expected without fail. Testing this process has involved dropping and recreating this table with each iteration.

I've done the usual sweep of process documentation/forums/etc., but can't see this being reported elsewhere. Is this a known issue that can be fixed by specifying additional parameters? I have a workaround for this (enclosing the create statement and unknown value prior to the rest of the procedure in my application, but I'd rather keep the script in as few parts as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the remaining columns have the correct values?  I suspect the error might be along those lines.

You can do this using `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO TBL (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT x.*
    FROM (SELECT 'Unknown' as col1, NULL as col2, 'Etc' as col3) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE tbl.user_key = -1)
```

Comment: The values would have been correct as the row was being correctly inserted to the empty table despite the User_Key not matching the seed.

Your workaround works perfectly - thank you.